# How to filter by page number and form

Tags: php, html, database, forms, post

I have a page that prints a log from the db.
On the page I have a form that can filter the viewed log by several parameters.
I also have separation by page numbers because I show on each page only specific number of records.
The question is, if someone's filters the log by a parameter, aka using the form.
 How do I show him a relevant list of page numbers that will include his filter?
The form uses POST, the page number list is just a collection of links to

```
log.php?page=x
```

How do I combine them both?

Comment: Are the pages indexed as classes?

Comment: What do you mean? css classes?

Comment: Nevermind, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: You want to say something like: "with this filter you'll get results from page 1,3 and 5 from the whole set of results"?

Comment: No, I want that for each filter you will get the relevant pages only with the relevant data.  If I have total 5 pages, and I filter by something, I want to see only the pages that the filter appears on, let's say 3.

Answer (score 0):

You need two things, the total number of records and the current page records. So you also need to do two queries.

Lets say your WHERE is something like

```
$where = "filter_a = 'b'";
```

Then your queries are:

```
$qAll = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table ".$where;
$qPage = "SELECT * FROM table ".$where." LIMIT 10,20
```

Limit used is an example, but i hope you get the idea

Comment: The problem is when the page is refreshed, you don't know what the query was when the submit button was pressed.
If I save it on a session, I don't know when I have to free the session so it won't filter anymore.

Comment: I think i don't understand it right, but why can't you reset the filter session every time the form is submitted? And optional you can add a 'clear' / 'reset' button or something within your filter, so the user can clear the filtered options when he likes?

Comment: Because if the user goes to another page and then comes back the session will still be set. I can add a reset button but it'll be less intuitive

Comment: I see. Maby you can reset the session on all the pages, except the on filter page(s). In that way, the filter keep intact as long as the user stay on the filter page(s). When leaving to an another page, the session is reset.